# Python - Pandas - Remove content between the first occurrence of a character and a fix string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Imagine that I have that dataframe:

```
data = {'Script': ["create table table_name ( col_1 string , col_2 string , col_3 string ) row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.lazysimpleserde' with properties ( 'field.delim' ='\t' , 'serialization.format' ='\t' , 'serialization.null.format'='' ) stored as inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.textinputformat' outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.hiveignorekeytextoutputformat' location 'hdfs://nameservice1/table_name'tblproperties ( 'parquet.compress'='snappy' );"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Basically, the content of the column is DDL:

```
create table table_name
  (
    col_1 string
  , col_2 string
  , col_3 string
  )
  row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.lazysimpleserde' with properties
  (
    'field.delim'              ='\t'
  , 'serialization.format'     ='\t'
  , 'serialization.null.format'=''
  )
  stored as inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.textinputformat' outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.hiveignorekeytextoutputformat' location 'hdfs://nameservice1/table_name'tblproperties
  (
    'parquet.compress'='snappy'
  )
```

What I need to do is to remove all the content between the fist "(" and the word "location". Basically my expected output is the following one:

```
create table table_name
  (
    col_1 string
  , col_2 string
  , col_3 string
  )
  location 'hdfs://nameservice1/table_name'tblproperties
  (
    'parquet.compress'='snappy'
  )
```

For that I am trying to use a regex approach:

```
df['DDL'] = df.Script.str.replace(r")", " } ").str.replace(r'<}^>location+>', "")
```

However, the result was not the desired one:

```
create table table_name
  (
    col_1 string
  , col_2 string
  , col_3 string
  }
  row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.lazysimpleserde' with properties
  (
    'field.delim'              ='\t'
  , 'serialization.format'     ='\t'
  , 'serialization.null.format'='' } stored as inputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.textinputformat' outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.hiveignorekeytextoutputformat' location 'hdfs://nameservice1/table_name'tblproperties ( 'parquet.compress'='snappy' }
;
```

What I am doing wrong? With my approach I am trying to extract between { and location...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df['DDL'] = df['Script'].str.replace(r"(?s)^([^)]*)\).*?\b(location)\b", r"\1\2")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lziWLn/1)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - an inline `re.DOTALL` option making `.` match line break chars
- `^` - start of string
- `([^)]*)` - Group 1 (`\1` in the replacement pattern): any 0+ chars other than `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible (`*?` is a non-greedy quantifier)
- `\b(location)\b` - Group 2  (`\2` in the replacement pattern) capturing a whole word `location` (`\b` stand for word boundaries)